# long blog post on self hosted wordpress blog not displayed

Tags: posts, blog

I have my self hosted wordpress blog [here](http://blog.geotitles.com/) I recently created a blog post which is very long with so many pictures and text, but i suddenly found that my blog post was not displayed
but if i cut short the length by deleting some content then the blog gets displayed
can anyone help ?
Thanks in advance
[here](http://blog.geotitles.com/2011/08/top-10-most-popular-file-upload-scripts-live-demo-and-free-downloadpart-1/) is the link to my blog post which is not getting displayed

Comment: Not sure what you mean - it's paginated but it all seems to display?

Comment: Yeah I used the next page tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really long posts need to be paginated in order to be dispalyed.
So using `<!--nextpage-->` tag I paginated the post and it finally works.

Comment: <!--nextpage--> I mean using next page tag